# How to call async method from an event handler?

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, async-await

I am a complete beginner with async/await, so any help would be great.

```
    async Task<bool> IsIPBannedAsync(string ip)
    {
        try
        {
            bool isBanned = false;

            await foreach (var line in File.ReadLinesAsync(BannedIPFile))
            {
                if(line.Contains(ip.Trim())) { isBanned = true; break; }
            }
            return isBanned;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

I call that from a button to send the result to a label:

```
    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text = string.Empty;

        lblResult.Text = IsIPBannedAsync(txtIP.Text);
    }
```

Of course I have attempted to send the results using `Convert.ToBoolean()` | `Convert.ToString()` without success and get a `System.Threading` string rather than a boolean true | false.

Without async, I can get things to work:

```
    bool isBanned = false;
    isBanned = File.ReadLines(BannedIPFile).Contains(ip.Trim());
    return isBanned;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Appreciate it - thank you

UPDATE:

Those of you who cannot find what I posted, you can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlinesasync?view=net-7.0). I am using net core 7.0, in which it was introduced.

In the Button Click event, it doesn't like returning a boolean and asks for it to be converted to a string. All Microsoft solutions do not work.

If I change `Task<bool>` to `Task<string>` and then use return `IsBanned.ToString();` everywhere it works.

@ProgrammingLlama, I used VB since version 3 and went to most of the .NET launches at Microsoft but since around 2010, I haven't really bothered with coding at all, yet I still pay the money for my MSDN Enterprise Subscription each year, as a single person.

My VS version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.5.4

Some of my questions to the developer community of VS2022 have been referenced on this site many, many times as well as the MSDN site, back in the day.

The `ReadAllLinesAsync` comment is correct because why read a file all the way through if the answer is on line 1?

EDIT / UPDATE 2:

[Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542251/liam), it is **C#, Net Core 7** Desktop app, which will be put into a DLL and used on my friend's **net core 7.0 razor** website. I will be using this almost daily

Thank you to everyone for posting and I still have to work this out.

Comment: I couldn't find ReadLinesAsync, are you sure it is not ReadAllLinesAsync?

Comment: `private void btnCheck` -> `private async void btnCheck` and `lblResult.Text = IsIPBannedAsync(txtIP.Text);` -> `lblResult.Text = await IsIPBannedAsync(txtIP.Text);`

Comment: @Rosdi `ReadLinesAsync` was a red herring anyway.

Comment: Turtle, try this: 

`async Task<bool> IsIPBannedAsync(string ip)
{
    try
    {
        bool isBanned = false;

        var lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(BannedIPFile);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if(line.Contains(ip.Trim())) { isBanned = true; break; }
        }
        return isBanned;
    }
    catch { return false; }  //<-- btw, it is a bad practice to catch all exceptions
}`

Comment: I couldn't answer you since the question is closed.

Comment: @Rosdi What is the benefit of your proposed solution vs what OP already has? The method will still return a `Task<bool>` even with your "solution", meaning that the problem that led to OP asking this question will still exist. All you've done is made the solution worse because it's now necessary to read _all lines_ from the file even if the banned IP is on the very first line.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama He is just learning programming, right now his code won't even compile. I am not focused on performance here. I am sure he will be able to figure out the rest once he got his code to at least compiles.

Comment: @Rosdi But your answer doesn't actually solve the problem. OP's code compiles.

Comment: @Rosdi [Compiling code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBXgq5).

Comment: `btnCheck_Click` what technology is this? WPF?

Comment: @RosdiKasim the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Everyone and thank you for all your suggestions. I found it as easy as the click event, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async).

In short:

```
private async void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool IsBanned = await IsIPBannedAsync(txtIP.Text);

    lblResult.Text = IsBanned.ToString();

}

public async Task<bool> IsIPBannedAsync(string ip)
{
    try
    {
        bool IsBanned = false;

        await foreach (var line in File.ReadLinesAsync(IPFileList))
        {
            if (line.Contains(ip.Trim())) { IsBanned = true; break; }
        }
        return IsBanned;
    }
    catch { return false; } // This was done for ease here.
}
```

and yes, it compiles.